# How do I display the Value of an option in a HTML selecty dropdown menu beside the dropdown?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, display

I am creating a form calculation page based on HTML/CSS and Java and need to display the value of the option chosen from a SELECT dropdown beside the dropdown as well as the name of the option inside the cell as is.

I haven't tried a lot as I dont know where to start nor can I find an exact answer online

There is a fiddle below, I have used the basic cake form that's online and removed all fields I dont need(forgive the extra JAVA, didnt want to delete incase it didnt work)

https://jsfiddle.net/Snorlaxx/x3j2d1nm/3/

```
<style>
#wrap {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 8px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  font-family: AvenirLTStd, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 16px;
}

#wrap .cont_details fieldset,
.cont_order fieldset {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#wrap legend {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#wrap .cont_details input {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #000;
}

#wrap .input1:hover,
.input1:active {}

#wrap label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#wrap label.inlinelabel {
  display: inline;
}

#wrap .cont_order input {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#wrap .cont_order p {
  padding-top: 5px;
}

#wrap input[type="radio"] {
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

#wrap input[type="text"]:hover,
#wrap input[type="text"]:active {
  background-color: #FAF398;
}

#wrap input#submit {
  margin: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#wrap div#totalPrice {
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #ff0;
}

#wrap label.radiolabel {
  font-weight: normal;
  display: inline;
}
</style>
<script>
  /*
This source is shared under the terms of LGPL 3
www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html

You are free to use the code in Commercial or non-commercial projects
*/

//Set up an associative array
//The keys represent the size of the cake
//The values represent the cost of the cake i.e A 10" cake cost's $35
var cake_prices = new Array();
cake_prices["Round6"] = 20;
cake_prices["Round8"] = 25;
cake_prices["Round10"] = 35;
cake_prices["Round12"] = 75;

//Set up an associative array 
//The keys represent the filling type
//The value represents the cost of the filling i.e. Lemon filling is $5,Dobash filling is $9
//We use this this array when the user selects a filling from the form
var filling_prices = new Array();
filling_prices["None"] = 0;
filling_prices["Lemon"] = 5;
filling_prices["Custard"] = 5;
filling_prices["Fudge"] = 7;
filling_prices["Mocha"] = 8;
filling_prices["Raspberry"] = 10;
filling_prices["Pineapple"] = 5;
filling_prices["Dobash"] = 9;
filling_prices["Mint"] = 5;
filling_prices["Cherry"] = 5;
filling_prices["Apricot"] = 8;
filling_prices["Buttercream"] = 7;
filling_prices["Chocolate Mousse"] = 12;



// getCakeSizePrice() finds the price based on the size of the cake.
// Here, we need to take user's the selection from radio button selection
function getCakeSizePrice() {
  var cakeSizePrice = 0;
  //Get a reference to the form id="cakeform"
  var theForm = document.forms["cakeform"];
  //Get a reference to the cake the user Chooses name=selectedCake":
  var selectedCake = theForm.elements["selectedcake"];
  //Here since there are 4 radio buttons selectedCake.length = 4
  //We loop through each radio buttons
  for (var i = 0; i < selectedCake.length; i++) {
    //if the radio button is checked
    if (selectedCake[i].checked) {
      //we set cakeSizePrice to the value of the selected radio button
      //i.e. if the user choose the 8" cake we set it to 25
      //by using the cake_prices array
      //We get the selected Items value
      //For example cake_prices["Round8".value]"
      cakeSizePrice = cake_prices[selectedCake[i].value];
      //If we get a match then we break out of this loop
      //No reason to continue if we get a match
      break;
    }
  }
  //We return the cakeSizePrice
  return cakeSizePrice;
}

//This function finds the filling price based on the 
//drop down selection
function getFillingPrice() {
  var cakeFillingPrice = 0;
  //Get a reference to the form id="cakeform"
  var theForm = document.forms["cakeform"];
  //Get a reference to the select id="filling"
  var selectedFilling = theForm.elements["filling"];

  //set cakeFilling Price equal to value user chose
  //For example filling_prices["Lemon".value] would be equal to 5
  cakeFillingPrice = filling_prices[selectedFilling.value];

  //finally we return cakeFillingPrice
  return cakeFillingPrice;
}

//candlesPrice() finds the candles price based on a check box selection
function candlesPrice() {
  var candlePrice = 0;
  //Get a reference to the form id="cakeform"
  var theForm = document.forms["cakeform"];
  //Get a reference to the checkbox id="includecandles"
  var includeCandles = theForm.elements["includecandles"];

  //If they checked the box set candlePrice to 5
  if (includeCandles.checked == true) {
    candlePrice = 5;
  }
  //finally we return the candlePrice
  return candlePrice;
}

function insciptionPrice() {
  //This local variable will be used to decide whether or not to charge for the inscription
  //If the user checked the box this value will be 20
  //otherwise it will remain at 0
  var inscriptionPrice = 0;
  //Get a refernce to the form id="cakeform"
  var theForm = document.forms["cakeform"];
  //Get a reference to the checkbox id="includeinscription"
  var includeInscription = theForm.elements["includeinscription"];
  //If they checked the box set inscriptionPrice to 20
  if (includeInscription.checked == true) {
    inscriptionPrice = 20;
  }
  //finally we return the inscriptionPrice
  return inscriptionPrice;
}

function calculateTotal() {
  //Here we get the total price by calling our function
  //Each function returns a number so by calling them we add the values they return together
  var cakePrice = getCakeSizePrice() + getFillingPrice() + candlesPrice() + insciptionPrice();

  //display the result
  var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
  divobj.style.display = 'block';
  divobj.innerHTML = "Total Price For the Cake $" + cakePrice;

}

function hideTotal() {
  var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
  divobj.style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Cake Form</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/formcalculations.js"></script>
    <link href="styles/cakeform.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>

  <body onload='hideTotal()'>
    <div id="wrap">
      <form action="" id="cakeform" onsubmit="return false;">
        <div>
          <div class="cont_order">
            <fieldset>
              <legend>Make your cake!</legend>
              <label>Filling</label>
              <select id="filling" name='filling' onchange="calculateTotal()">
                <option value="None">Select Filling</option>
                <option value="Lemon">Lemon($5)</option>
                <option value="Custard">Custard($5)</option>
                <option value="Fudge">Fudge($7)</option>
                <option value="Mocha">Mocha($8)</option>
                <option value="Raspberry">Raspberry($10)</option>
                <option value="Pineapple">Pineapple($5)</option>
                <option value="Dobash">Dobash($9)</option>
                <option value="Mint">Mint($5)</option>
                <option value="Cherry">Cherry($5)</option>
                <option value="Apricot">Apricot($8)</option>
                <option value="Buttercream">Buttercream($7)</option>
                <option value="Chocolate Mousse">Chocolate Mousse($12)</option>
               </select>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <div id="totalPrice"></div>

            </fieldset>
          </div>
          <input type='submit' id='submit' value='Submit' onclick="calculateTotal()" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!--End of wrap-->

  </body>
        </html>
```

When an option is chosen, I need the Value of that option displayed to the right of the dropdown. I.E if someone choses Pineapple($5), I need Pineapple(which is the value) displayed to the right of the select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the value of the option selected, I've added a container to the right of the drop-down, and on change of the drop-down, the value of the option selected is moved to the container using innerHTML:

```js
window.onload = hideTotal();
/*
This source is shared under the terms of LGPL 3
www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html

You are free to use the code in Commercial or non-commercial projects
*/

//Set up an associative array
//The keys represent the size of the cake
//The values represent the cost of the cake i.e A 10" cake cost's $35
var cake_prices = new Array();
cake_prices["Round6"] = 20;
cake_prices["Round8"] = 25;
cake_prices["Round10"] = 35;
cake_prices["Round12"] = 75;

//Set up an associative array 
//The keys represent the filling type
//The value represents the cost of the filling i.e. Lemon filling is $5,Dobash filling is $9
//We use this this array when the user selects a filling from the form
var filling_prices = new Array();
filling_prices["None"] = 0;
filling_prices["Lemon"] = 5;
filling_prices["Custard"] = 5;
filling_prices["Fudge"] = 7;
filling_prices["Mocha"] = 8;
filling_prices["Raspberry"] = 10;
filling_prices["Pineapple"] = 5;
filling_prices["Dobash"] = 9;
filling_prices["Mint"] = 5;
filling_prices["Cherry"] = 5;
filling_prices["Apricot"] = 8;
filling_prices["Buttercream"] = 7;
filling_prices["Chocolate Mousse"] = 12;



// getCakeSizePrice() finds the price based on the size of the cake.
// Here, we need to take user's the selection from radio button selection
function getCakeSizePrice() {
  var cakeSizePrice = 0;
  //Get a reference to the form id="cakeform"
  var theForm = document.forms["cakeform"];
  //Get a reference to the cake the user Chooses name=selectedCake":
  var selectedCake = theForm.elements["selectedcake"];
  //Here since there are 4 radio buttons selectedCake.length = 4
  //We loop through each radio buttons
  for (var i = 0; i < selectedCake.length; i++) {
    //if the radio button is checked
    if (selectedCake[i].checked) {
      //we set cakeSizePrice to the value of the selected radio button
      //i.e. if the user choose the 8" cake we set it to 25
      //by using the cake_prices array
      //We get the selected Items value
      //For example cake_prices["Round8".value]"
      cakeSizePrice = cake_prices[selectedCake[i].value];
      //If we get a match then we break out of this loop
      //No reason to continue if we get a match
      break;
    }
  }
  //We return the cakeSizePrice
  return cakeSizePrice;
}

//This function finds the filling price based on the 
//drop down selection
function getFillingPrice() {
  var cakeFillingPrice = 0;
  //Get a reference to the form id="cakeform"
  var theForm = document.forms["cakeform"];
  //Get a reference to the select id="filling"
  var selectedFilling = theForm.elements["filling"];
  //
  var showValue = document.getElementById("showValue");

  //set cakeFilling Price equal to value user chose
  //For example filling_prices["Lemon".value] would be equal to 5
  cakeFillingPrice = filling_prices[selectedFilling.value];
  // Show the value of the selected option
  showValue.innerHTML = selectedFilling.value;

  //finally we return cakeFillingPrice
  return cakeFillingPrice;
}

//candlesPrice() finds the candles price based on a check box selection
function candlesPrice() {
  var candlePrice = 0;
  //Get a reference to the form id="cakeform"
  var theForm = document.forms["cakeform"];
  //Get a reference to the checkbox id="includecandles"
  var includeCandles = theForm.elements["includecandles"];

  //If they checked the box set candlePrice to 5
  if (includeCandles.checked == true) {
    candlePrice = 5;
  }
  //finally we return the candlePrice
  return candlePrice;
}

function insciptionPrice() {
  //This local variable will be used to decide whether or not to charge for the inscription
  //If the user checked the box this value will be 20
  //otherwise it will remain at 0
  var inscriptionPrice = 0;
  //Get a refernce to the form id="cakeform"
  var theForm = document.forms["cakeform"];
  //Get a reference to the checkbox id="includeinscription"
  var includeInscription = theForm.elements["includeinscription"];
  //If they checked the box set inscriptionPrice to 20
  if (includeInscription.checked == true) {
    inscriptionPrice = 20;
  }
  //finally we return the inscriptionPrice
  return inscriptionPrice;
}

function calculateTotal() {
  //Here we get the total price by calling our function
  //Each function returns a number so by calling them we add the values they return together
  var cakePrice = getCakeSizePrice() + getFillingPrice() + candlesPrice() + insciptionPrice();

  //display the result
  var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
  divobj.style.display = 'block';
  divobj.innerHTML = "Total Price For the Cake $" + cakePrice;

}

function hideTotal() {
  var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
  divobj.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
#wrap {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 8px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  font-family: AvenirLTStd, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 16px;
}

#wrap .cont_details fieldset,
.cont_order fieldset {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#wrap legend {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#wrap .cont_details input {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #000;
}

#wrap .input1:hover,
.input1:active {}

#wrap label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#wrap label.inlinelabel {
  display: inline;
}

#wrap .cont_order input {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#wrap .cont_order p {
  padding-top: 5px;
}

#wrap input[type="radio"] {
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

#wrap input[type="text"]:hover,
#wrap input[type="text"]:active {
  background-color: #FAF398;
}

#wrap input#submit {
  margin: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#wrap div#totalPrice {
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #ff0;
}

#wrap label.radiolabel {
  font-weight: normal;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <form action="" id="cakeform" onsubmit="return false;">
    <div>
      <div class="cont_order">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Make your cake!</legend>
          <label>Size</label>
          <input type="radio" name="selectedcake" value="Round6" required onchange="calculateTotal()"> 6"
          <input type="radio" name="selectedcake" value="Round8" required onchange="calculateTotal()"> 8"
          <input type="radio" name="selectedcake" value="Round10" required onchange="calculateTotal()"> 10"
          <input type="radio" name="selectedcake" value="Round12" required onchange="calculateTotal()"> 12"<br><br>

          <label>Filling</label>
          <select id="filling" name='filling' onchange="calculateTotal()" required>
            <option value="">Select Filling</option>
            <option value="Lemon">Lemon($5)</option>
            <option value="Custard">Custard($5)</option>
            <option value="Fudge">Fudge($7)</option>
            <option value="Mocha">Mocha($8)</option>
            <option value="Raspberry">Raspberry($10)</option>
            <option value="Pineapple">Pineapple($5)</option>
            <option value="Dobash">Dobash($9)</option>
            <option value="Mint">Mint($5)</option>
            <option value="Cherry">Cherry($5)</option>
            <option value="Apricot">Apricot($8)</option>
            <option value="Buttercream">Buttercream($7)</option>
            <option value="Chocolate Mousse">Chocolate Mousse($12)</option>
          </select> <span id="showValue"></span>
          <br/><br/> Include candles <input type="checkbox" name="includecandles" id="includecandles" onchange="calculateTotal()">
          <br/><br/> Include inscription <input type="checkbox" name="includeinscription" id="includeinscription" onchange="calculateTotal()">
          <br/><br/>
          <div id="totalPrice"></div>

        </fieldset>
      </div>
      <input type='submit' id='submit' value='Submit' onclick="calculateTotal()" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Michael. I understand they are the steps for the total cost, but the requirement is to display the value of the option chosen and to display it right of the drop down menu.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. Just to confirm, If the user selects Lemon($5) from the selection list, you want the value of the selected option, which in this case is lemon, to be displayed to the right of the drop-down? I've changed the snippet to do this, but let me know if I've still got it wrong.